# Validation rule - accept blank or a value with a certain format

Tags: validation-rule

Have been playing with validation rules for sometime, not been able to handle all the conditions, but was able to make most of it work so far.
I want to create a validation rule that can accept a blank value or if a value is entered it should be of a specific format.

Here is the one I have created, this seems to be working so far on validating the format but not allowing blank values.

```
NOT(boolean_field__c)
&&
LOWER(LEFT(theField__c,4)) <> "def-"
||
NOT(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(theField__c,(LEN(theField__c)-FIND('-',theField__c)))))
||
NOT(ISBLANK(theField__c))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it easier to think of this logic in a positive sense - what is a good value rather than what is a bad value, then slap a `NOT()` around it all to make it a validation rule that returns TRUE when *invalid*. E.g.:

```
NOT(ISBLANK(theField__c) || REGEX(theField__c, "def-[0-9]+"))
```

Over all your expression would be `NOT(boolean_field__c) && X`, where X is the above expression. Note that this is like `NOT(A) && NOT(B)`, which is the same as `NOT(A || B)` (as per [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)), so your whole expression can be:

```
NOT(boolean_field__c || ISBLANK(theField__c) || REGEX(theField__c, "def-[0-9]+"))
```

Comment: Thank Phil, you made the whole thing super simple to understand and implement.